# How to pass formData(fileupload) through jquery ajax along with MVC model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My script :

```
            //FILE UPLOAD
            var formData = new FormData();
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];

                formData.append("FileUpload", file);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: BASE_URL + "/BEHome/AddImgSlide/",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('#ImgSlideForm').serializeArray(), //SEND MODEL
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    //do something
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    //do something
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    //do something
                }
            });
```

My controller :

```
void AddImgSlide(ImageSlideModel model)
{
    //do something
}
```

I'm trying to pass formData along with $('#ImgSlideForm').serializeArray() but have no idea how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try just passing the form to the FormData constuctor and send that as the data

```
       var formData = new FormData($('#ImgSlideForm')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: BASE_URL + "/BEHome/AddImgSlide/",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false, 
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                //do something
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //do something
            },
            error: function (data) {
                //do something
            }
        });
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to send my model(stored in $('#ImgSlideForm').serializeArray()) and my fileupload (stored in var 'formData').

Comment: Is `FileUpload` inside `ImgSlideForm`?

Comment: Then the above should work, given that the server side is set up properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can send both model data and file at the same time using FormData  like this example:

```
    <form id="create-form" >
              Name: <input  id="Name" type="text" name="Name">
             <br />
              Password: <input id="Edit-Password" type="password" name="Password">
              <br />
            <div>
                <div>Upload Image</div>
                <div>
                    <input type="file" name="UploadImage" id="UploadImage">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="ImageId" id="ImageId" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="UserId" id="UserId" value="" />
         <input type="submit" id="SubmitBtn" />
   </form>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
           var formdata = new FormData();
           var fileInput = document.getElementById("UploadImage");
           formdata.append('Name', $('#Name').val());
           formdata.append('Password', $('#Password').val());
           if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
                   formdata.append(fileInput.files[0].name, fileInput.files[0]);
                 }
            $("#SubmitBtn").click(function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();

                   $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: BASE_URL + "/BEHome/AddImgSlide/",
                      dataType: 'json',
                      data: formdata ,
                      contentType: false,
                      processData: false, 

                      success: function (data) {
                       //do something
                      },
                      error: function (data) {
                     //do something
                      }
                  });
            });
      });
   </script>
```